# why is using assertion frameworks in production code bad?

Tags: java, assertion

Java has the keyword `assert` but this must be enabled with `java -ea`. So I come to the idea instead of having a *validation framework*, to use an *assertion framework* (like assertj) in **production code**. But it seems to be bad practice regarding https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-5960. I don't know why, because validations and assertions are similar.

Does anyone know an *assertion framework* explicitly recommended for production code? Or should I do the old way:

```
if(!isValid(x)){
throw new IllegalArgumentException("value not valid.");
}
```

instead of something like:

```
assert x
```

Comment: Did you read the explanations at that link? If so, what about them do is not clear to you?

Comment: It does explain **very opiniated** why I should not use it. Do you think assert is bad for production code? I don't think so. I think, it reduces and improves code. And all the rules, the most are good, but that does not mean, we should not questioning it.

Answer (score -2):

I have used our self-developed assertions in a production environment, for example:

Member memberDb = memberDao.findMemberByPhoneNumberAndPassWordAndProduct(member.getPhoneNumber(), member.getPassWord(), ProductType.BOOKING.ordinal());
Asserts.asserts(null!= memberDb, ErrorType.USERNAME_OR_PASSWORD_ERROR);

It can work very well, if you need, I will reply to you in detail.